# My iOS App with WebRTC crash while returning certificate for ssl

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, webrtc

I've built the fat WebRTC.framework and I put it into my xcode project, I'm using swift language and this is the viewDidLoad method of the main ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let stun = "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
    let list = [stun]
    let rtcIceServer = RTCIceServer(urlStrings: list)

 if RTCInitializeSSL() {
        RTCDispatcher.dispatchAsync(on: .typeMain, block: {
            let factory = RTCPeerConnectionFactory()
            let config = RTCConfiguration()
            config.iceServers = [rtcIceServer]
            let const = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: [:], optionalConstraints: nil)
            let peerConnection = factory.peerConnection(with: config, constraints: const, delegate: self)
        })
    }
}
```

when I run the app on an ipad 2 with iOS 9.3.5, the app crashes and show this lines at the end of the log:

```
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:574): WebRtcVoiceEngine::WebRtcVoiceEngine
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:581): Supported send codecs in order of preference:
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: opus/48000/2 (111)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: ISAC/16000/1 (103)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: G722/8000/1 (9)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: ILBC/8000/1 (102)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: PCMU/8000/1 (0)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: PCMA/8000/1 (8)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: CN/32000/1 (106)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: CN/16000/1 (105)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: CN/8000/1 (13)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: telephone-event/48000/1 (110)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: telephone-event/32000/1 (112)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: telephone-event/16000/1 (113)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:319): Adding supported codec: telephone-event/8000/1 (126)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): opus/48000/2 (111)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): ISAC/16000/1 (103)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): G722/8000/1 (9)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): ILBC/8000/1 (102)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): PCMU/8000/1 (0)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): PCMA/8000/1 (8)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): CN/32000/1 (106)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): CN/16000/1 (105)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): CN/8000/1 (13)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): telephone-event/48000/1 (110)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): telephone-event/32000/1 (112)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): telephone-event/16000/1 (113)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:584): telephone-event/8000/1 (126)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:587): Supported recv codecs in order of preference:
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): opus/48000/2 (111)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): isac/16000/1 (103)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): G722/8000/1 (9)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): iLBC/8000/1 (102)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): PCMU/8000/1 (0)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): PCMA/8000/1 (8)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): cn/16000/1 (105)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): cn/8000/1 (13)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): telephone-event/48000/1 (110)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): telephone-event/16000/1 (113)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:590): telephone-event/8000/1 (126)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:598): VoiceEngine 4.1.0
(audio_device_impl.cc:86): Create
(audio_device_buffer.cc:73): AudioDeviceBuffer::ctor
(audio_device_impl.cc:133): AudioDeviceModuleImpl
(audio_device_impl.cc:141): CheckPlatform
(audio_device_impl.cc:158): current platform is IOS
(audio_device_impl.cc:182): CreatePlatformSpecificObjects
(audio_device_impl.cc:1876): PlatformAudioLayer
(audio_device_ios.mm:104): AudioDeviceIOS::ctor<NSThread: 0x165ef190>{number = 3, name = (null)}
(audio_device_impl.cc:324): iPhone Audio APIs will be utilized
(audio_device_impl.cc:371): AttachAudioBuffer
(audio_device_ios.mm:118): AudioDeviceIOS::AttachAudioBuffer
(audio_device_impl.cc:1484): RegisterEventObserver
(audio_device_impl.cc:1497): RegisterAudioCallback
(audio_device_buffer.cc:88): RegisterAudioCallback
(audio_device_impl.cc:499): Init
(audio_device_ios.mm:125): AudioDeviceIOS::Init
(audio_device_ios.mm:76): LogDeviceInfo
(audio_device_ios.mm:78):  system name: iPhone OS
(audio_device_ios.mm:79):  system version 1(2): 9.3.5
(audio_device_ios.mm:80):  system version 2(2): 9.3
(audio_device_ios.mm:81):  device type: iPad
(audio_device_ios.mm:82):  device name: iPad2,2
(audio_device_ios.mm:83):  process name: AppRTC
(audio_device_ios.mm:84):  process ID: 2415
(audio_device_ios.mm:85):  OS version: Version 9.3.5 (Build 13G36)
(audio_device_ios.mm:86):  processing cores: 2
(audio_device_ios.mm:89):  low power mode: 0
(audio_device_ios.mm:579): AudioDeviceIOS::UpdateAudioDevicebuffer
(audio_device_buffer.cc:196): SetPlayoutSampleRate(48000)
(audio_device_buffer.cc:220): SetPlayoutChannels(1)
(audio_device_buffer.cc:189): SetRecordingSampleRate(48000)
(audio_device_buffer.cc:213): SetRecordingChannels(1)
(audio_device_impl.cc:1228): SetPlayoutDevice(0)
(audio_device_not_implemented_ios.mm:111): virtual int32_t webrtc::AudioDeviceIOS::SetPlayoutDevice(uint16_t): Not implemented
(audio_device_impl.cc:548): InitSpeaker
(audio_device_impl.cc:1323): SetRecordingDevice(0)
(audio_device_not_implemented_ios.mm:260): virtual int32_t webrtc::AudioDeviceIOS::SetRecordingDevice(uint16_t): Not implemented
(audio_device_impl.cc:558): InitMicrophone
(audio_device_impl.cc:1037): StereoPlayoutIsAvailable
(audio_device_impl.cc:1047): output: 0
(audio_device_impl.cc:1056): SetStereoPlayout(0)
(audio_device_not_implemented_ios.mm:195): virtual int32_t webrtc::AudioDeviceIOS::SetStereoPlayout(bool): Not implemented
(audio_device_impl.cc:1066): stereo playout is not supported
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:1044): webrtc: Init() failed to set mono/stereo playout mode (error=8090)
(audio_device_impl.cc:923): StereoRecordingIsAvailable
(audio_device_impl.cc:933): output: 0
(audio_device_impl.cc:942): SetStereoRecording(0)
(audio_device_not_implemented_ios.mm:180): virtual int32_t webrtc::AudioDeviceIOS::SetStereoRecording(bool): Not implemented
(audio_device_impl.cc:951): failed to change stereo recording
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:1044): webrtc: Init() failed to set mono/stereo recording mode (error=8090)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:1044): webrtc: TransmitMixer::SetAudioProcessingModule(audioProcessingModule=0x168e3000)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:1044): webrtc: OutputMixer::SetAudioProcessingModule(audioProcessingModule=0x168e3000)
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:1044): webrtc: (audio_processing_impl.cc:640): Level controller activated: 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:1044): webrtc: (audio_processing_impl.cc:647): Highpass filter activated: 1
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:673): WebRtcVoiceEngine::ApplyOptions: AudioOptions {aec: true, agc: true, ns: true, hf: true, swap: false, audio_jitter_buffer_max_packets: 50, audio_jitter_buffer_fast_accelerate: false, typing: true, agc_delta: 0, experimental_agc: false, extended_filter_aec: false, delay_agnostic_aec: false, experimental_ns: false, intelligibility_enhancer: false, level_control: false, residual_echo_detector: false, }
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:692): Always disable AEC, NS and AGC on iOS. Use built-in instead.
(audio_device_impl.cc:1792): BuiltInAECIsAvailable
(audio_device_generic.cc:51): virtual bool webrtc::AudioDeviceGeneric::BuiltInAECIsAvailable() const: Not supported on this platform
(audio_device_impl.cc:1795): output: 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:754): Echo control set to 0 with mode 2
(audio_device_impl.cc:1808): BuiltInAGCIsAvailable
(audio_device_generic.cc:61): virtual bool webrtc::AudioDeviceGeneric::BuiltInAGCIsAvailable() const: Not supported on this platform
(audio_device_impl.cc:1811): output: 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:788): Auto gain set to 0 with mode 4
(audio_device_impl.cc:1824): BuiltInNSIsAvailable
(audio_device_generic.cc:71): virtual bool webrtc::AudioDeviceGeneric::BuiltInNSIsAvailable() const: Not supported on this platform
(audio_device_impl.cc:1827): output: 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:843): Noise suppression set to 0 with mode 5
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:849): Stereo swapping enabled? 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:858): NetEq capacity is 50
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:864): NetEq fast mode? 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:871): Typing detection is enabled? 0
(voe_audio_processing_impl.cc:685): virtual int webrtc::VoEAudioProcessingImpl::SetTypingDetectionStatus(bool): not supported
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:875): SetTypingDetectionStatus(0) failed, err=8003
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:880): Adjust agc delta is 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:1069): Adjusting AGC level from default -3dB to -3dB
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:891): Delay agnostic aec is enabled? 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:900): Extended filter aec is enabled? 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:909): Experimental ns is enabled? 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:915): Intelligibility Enhancer is enabled? 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:925): Level control: 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:1044): webrtc: (audio_processing_impl.cc:640): Level controller activated: 0
(webrtcvoiceengine.cc:1044): webrtc: (audio_processing_impl.cc:647): Highpass filter activated: 1
(audio_device_impl.cc:1497): RegisterAudioCallback
(audio_device_buffer.cc:88): RegisterAudioCallback
(audio_device_impl.cc:1497): RegisterAudioCallback
(audio_device_buffer.cc:88): RegisterAudioCallback
(webrtcvideoengine2.cc:466): WebRtcVideoEngine2::WebRtcVideoEngine2()
(webrtcvideoengine2.cc:474): WebRtcVideoEngine2::Init
(webrtcvideoengine2.cc:606): Internally supported codecs: {VideoCodec[0:VP8], VideoCodec[0:VP9], VideoCodec[0:red], VideoCodec[0:ulpfec]}
(webrtcvideoengine2.cc:616): Codecs supported by the external encoder factory: {VideoCodec[0:H264]}
(opensslidentity.cc:41): Making key pair
(opensslidentity.cc:89): Returning key pair
(opensslidentity.cc:96): Making certificate for WebRTC
(opensslidentity.cc:144): Returning certificate
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you attach the stack trace ?

Comment: @manishganvir I have just put the entire log

Comment: I need the stacktrace aka backtrace

Comment: able to solve it

Comment: @Roran, were you able to solve this?